MAUI .NET 8 - Absolute layout height size is not same as in Portrait and Landscape mode
In my MAUI project, I used AbsoluteLayout to define a UI design. However, I found that AbsoluteLayout height proportional is the same as in Portrait and Landscape.
The height size differs, For example,
In Portrait mode,

In Landscape mode,

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
screenWidth = width;
screenHeight = height;
double lytheight = screenHeight * 0.10;
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stkNavigationBar, new Rect(0, 0,width,lytheight)); 
}

10% of the screen height I gave to the layout, but in landscape mode, the height size is small when comparing portrait mode.
is there any way to make the height size is same in both portrait and landscape mode?

What are you trying to do?
the screen in landscape mode has smaller height.
for example, if the screen size in portrait mode is 2340x1080 in landscape mode it will be 1080x2340 (the height decrease, and the width increase) so 10% of the height in portrait mode will be 234, in landscape mode it would be 108.
you can either set a MinimumHeight for the stkNavigationBar or set the HeightRequest to a static size 100px, 150px, 200px, ...etc.
another way to do this (which is better I think) is using the Grid control.
however, Maui has a built in NavigationBar it can be used in a NavigationPage.
If you are using Shell for navigation, it also contains a built in NavigationBar

That would be a fixed height rather than %. You could also do a % of the larger width and height.
